# Concatenate a string to column names

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I need to add a string "Test" to the beginning of each column name in an excel sheet. I have almost 100 columns so it would be difficult to do that manually for each column.

Is there a way I can do that using find and replace?  Or is there a different way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sounds elaborate, but it actually is pretty quick to do.

1. Insert a row (#1) above the column row (now #2)
2. In A1 create a formula `="Test"&A2`
3. Copy that formula across to all cells in row #1
4. Insert another row (#1) above the formula row (now #2) and the original (now #3)
5. Copy all cells in row #2 to row #1 **by Value (important)**
6. Delete rows #2 and #3

Comment: Why not paste back into the original row right away, like done in the first answer? That way you're sure any references to that row are not lost?

Comment: Just as a safety measure, and it's slightly less confusing.

Comment: Safety measure for what? (And again: it will actually mess up if the cells are referenced?)

Answer (score 2):

Insert a row above your column names. Then use this formula in each column above: `=CONCATENATE("Test",A2)` You can enter the formula in the first column, then copy and paste it to the rest. Use of A2 implies your headings start in that cell.

After you paste the formula, you can copy the cells and then *Paste Special* to paste only text back into the cells.